# Загрузка нескольких изображений к товару в Mysql на Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, база-данных, изображения

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать загрузку нескольких путей изображений к одному товару в базе данных mysql на python?

Суть вопроса.

Есть xml файл который разобран в список dict его содержимое выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в таблице products есть вот такие поля в строках.. то есть img_1 img_2 и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос. как вытащить первый элемент из списка (путь к изображению) и положить его в ячейку img_1 затем так же сделать со вторым элементом и положить в ячейку img_2 и т.д.

пните плиз в нужное направление..

Answer (score 1):

```
# Исходный словарь
d = {'price': 1555, 'picture': ['pathddd1', 'pathasdfa2', 'path///sdfsa2']} 
# По ключу берем нужный список путей 
path = d.get('picture')
# В цикле проходим по списку
for p in path:   
      print(p)  
    # Кода для добавление строки в Вашу БД
```

Comment: Спасибо @Andrey что дали ответ) но я решил использовать сериализацию с json с сохранением имени продукта и изображений) затем просто по ключу их искать по запросу, решил что это удобно для меня:) Если кто столкнется, могу скинуть пример, как я это сделал